# Excel VBA - how to make module windows dockable

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'd like to see modules in small windows so I can jump between them. Once I have extended one module across workspace, I can not get back to previous view

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean seeing the code windows?  Use Window -> Tile Horizontally or Window -> Tile Vertically to show all module windows using a non-overlapping view.

EDIT: If you maximize a module window, just restore it using the icon in the top-right.  It will snap back to its original position (where you set it) so you don't have to rearrange all the module windows again.